# SpringBoot not able to read from vault generic location

Tags: spring, spring-boot, consul, hashicorp-vault

In my Vault and Consul integration i have following secrets engine enble

```
[root@user ConsulSetup]# vault secrets list -detailed
Path          Plugin       Accessor              Default TTL    Max TTL    Force No Cache    Replication    Seal Wrap    Options           Description
----          ------       --------              -----------    -------    --------------    -----------    ---------    -------           -----------
cubbyhole/    cubbyhole    cubbyhole_f6352b88    n/a            n/a        false             local          false        map[]             per-token private secret storage
identity/     identity     identity_9ba1824c     system         system     false             replicated     false        map[]             identity store
kv/           kv           kv_864b2492           system         system     false             replicated     false        map[version:2]    n/a
sys/          system       system_0064db30       n/a            n/a        false             replicated     false        map[]             system endpoints used for control, policy and debugging
```

After this i added key/value from this command

```
vault kv put kv/demo/dev spring.datasource.username=demo-user-dev spring.datasource.password=demo-pass-dev
```

Now i want to read these value via SpringBoot Application so here is my bootstrap.yml file

```
spring:
    cloud:
        # Configuration for a vault server running in dev mode
        vault:
            scheme: http
            host: <HOSTIP>
            port: 8200
            connection-timeout: 5000
            read-timeout: 15000
            authentication: TOKEN
            token: <TOKEN>
            kv.enabled: true
            generic:
                enabled: true
                backend: kv
                profile-separator: '/'

logging:
    level:
        ROOT: WARN
```

Now i am trying to run the code

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import static org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active:#{null}}")
    private String profiles;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${other.username}")
    private String other;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("##########################");
        System.out.println("profile(s): " + profiles);
        System.out.println("username: " + username);
        System.out.println("password: " + password);
        System.out.println("other: " + other);

        dataSource.getConnection();
        System.out.println("Successfully connected to database");
        System.out.println("##########################");

        isTrue (!username.equals("to-be-overwritten-by-vault-value"), "Username " + username);
        isTrue (!password.equals("to-be-overwritten-by-vault-value"), "Password " + password);
    }

}
```

Which is end with following error

> #################### profile(s): null username: to-be-overwritten-by-vault-value password:
>
> to-be-overwritten-by-vault-value other:
>   to-be-overwritten-by-vault-value Successfully connected to database
>
> #################### 2019-05-30 15:31:39.147  WARN 18680 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'demoApplication': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Username to-be-overwritten-by-vault-value 2019-05-30 15:31:39.178
>   ERROR 18680 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>   : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'demoApplication': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Username to-be-overwritten-by-vault-value     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:33)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Username
>   to-be-overwritten-by-vault-value  at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:92)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   com.example.demo.DemoApplication.postConstruct(DemoApplication.java:48)
>   [classes/:na]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   ... 17 common frames
>   omitted

When i have vault integrated with file system that time path was something like `secret\key` it was working fine with this new changes its stop working.

Answer (score 0):

The exception actually does not seem to be related to vault though. It says

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Username to-be-overwritten-by-vault-value
```

Is it that you have a space in the default values that you have defined in the properties file?

Comment: If i am changing `backend: cubbyhole` same code working fine i am getting result.